# Dynamic updating values in Excel with absolute reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Let's say I have a data table in Excel that consists statistics of a population:

[image]

In percentage column, each cell is calculated by taking the ratio of "counts / total counts",  in which the **total counts** is fixed to `B$8`.

Now, if I copy this table to another location, the **total counts** would still point to the original cell `B$8`, while all other relative references update their locations automatically.

Is there an *automated/smart* way that I can make all formulas in the copied table to know the new location of **total counts** and use that new cell location instead?

Comment: I'm sure you'll probably receive an answer here in the next few minutes, but keep in mind that Stack Overflow is for programming questions - and sometimes questions relating to __complex__ formulas. This would have been much better suited for [su].

Comment: For better understanding share Screen Shot with us,, also the error message if getting any !!

Comment: **Cont,,** are you pasting in another Sheet?

Comment: I can't replicate this, Excel simply changes the references accordingly for me.

Comment: I think what @GTwu meant is moving the entire table to a different place in the same sheet i.e moving `A1:C8` to `D10:F17`, that all relative references will update but `B$8` which is absolute.

Comment: @RajeshS, No, I am parsing to the same sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula in place of `B$8`

```
VLOOKUP("Total",A1:B99,2,0)
```

Comment: Put some illustration like sample data to justify the Solution,, will attract more readers to appreciate all this!!